# Toggle navigation bar build using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For this question please resize your screen width to less than 600px. When screen is less than 600 px, it works perfectly but when the screen becomes larger than 600px its display become none spmehow ?
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Navbar Toggle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="toggle">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </li>
                <div id="flex">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trends</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
   * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #019031;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar #flex {
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar #flex a {
  font-size: 5vh;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navbar #flex a:hover {
  background-color: #333945;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.toggle .bar1, .toggle .bar2, .toggle .bar3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 6px 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #flex {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar #flex a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0];

toggle.addEventListener("click",myToggle,false);

function myToggle(){
    toggle.classList.toggle("change"); 
}


toggle.addEventListener("click",navFunction,false);

function navFunction(){
    var itemsDisplay = document.getElementById("flex");

    if (itemsDisplay.style.display === "flex") {
        itemsDisplay.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        itemsDisplay.style.display = "flex";
      }
}
```

**Please help me regarding this question. I am new to javascript. I really appreciate if someone help me. Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you exactly mean

> its display become none somehow?

I tested your code, working fine for me [(link)](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GE76O9Q41UCS)

If you mean `.navbar .toggle`, yes it is becoming display none above screen width 600px.

Here

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #flex {
    display: none;
```

Comment: when I resize the screen to less than 600 px the toggle bar works perfectly but whenI resize the screen to more than 600px the whole nav bar display gone ?

Comment: It was the intention of the above code, you shared. Remove `display:none` inside @media query and check.

Comment: Did you check my demo [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GE76O9Q41UCS) ?? Is it producing your issue??